# How do tasks work in JStorm?

Tags: apache-storm, jstorm

It seems there is no conception of *executors* in JStorm and the method `setTasksNumber()` seems useless because the number of tasks is related to `parallelism_hint`.

My question: are tasks in JStorm static? If not, when a task is dead, will it  restart? And if task not static, how does `fields-grouping` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JStorm, a worker behaves like an executor in Storm. A worker can have multiple tasks, but unlike Storm, the tasks within a worker may belong to different components, let's have an example:

A topology contains a spout (S), 2 bolts (B1, B2), the task number of each component is set when calling `TopologyBuilder.buildTopology` method, specifically in `TopologyBuilder.setBolt` method.

So let's say you set your S's parallelism to 2, and B1's parallelism to 3, B2's to 4. We'll have 2+3+4 = 9 tasks in total.

Then you may set total worker num to 3 by calling `Config.setNumWorkers()` method.

After scheduling the workers & tasks, we have task id's and components like this:

`B1: taskId: 1,2,3
S: taskId: 4,5
B2: taskId: 6,7,8,9`

Note that task id's within the same component are consecutive, but it don't necessarily start from spouts to bolts.

Then we have the following scheduled workers and tasks:

`Worker1: 1 4 6
Worker2: 2 5 7
Worker3: 3 8 9`

As we can see, each worker has 3 tasks, the task may be of different components.

Note that JStorm's scheduling algorithm is a little alike with Storm's default scheduling algorithm (but more powerful), please refer to this comparison:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1320

During the running period of your topology, if you don't perform a rebalance operation, the scheduled results will always be the same, i.e., no matter which host + port (worker) is assigned, the tasks within this worker is always the same. Even by restarting the topology, if you don't change the parallelism of your components, the scheduled results will be the same. But if you perform a rebalance operation, tasks may change.

When some task in a worker dies (by throwing an unchecked/unhandled exception), the whole worker will be killed and the error will be reported to ZK. The worker is rescheduled immediately, note that `reschedule` may not be accurately appropriate here, nimbus knows this worker is dead, it will just try to restart the worker elsewhere, but the tasks within this worker are exactly the same.

For more JStorm docs, please refer to: https://github.com/alibaba/jstorm

Comment: Thanks foryour answer,but I don't know when i do the rebanlan,task changed,how does fields-grouping work?

Comment: Before rebalancing, JStorm will deactivate all workers, which means no tuples will be sent during this period, and after knowing the new worker/task assignments(scale-in / scale-out), it will reset each worker's context, and will update the send targets & corresponding groupings, then it will activate all workers, thus all tuples will be sent according to the new groupings.

Comment: When i use trident in jstorm,tuples in one batch which have same fields will be send to different tasks after rebalance,so how does the trident's CombinerAggregator work?